# Change a normal table to a foreign "cstore_fdw" table

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, cstore-fdw

Is it possible to change a normal table to a foreign table in Postgresql?

At least, if it's not possible, can I copy data from a normal table to a foreign table?

Comment: It does not make much sence. but yes - if you save all data from local table to remote destination and create foreign table from that destination it will be the case. probably put more details - why you want to do such a strange thing?..

Comment: I'm actually working on a big data base (around 8 millions rows) and i want to try a lot of things to decrease the time for execute query. So I install cstore_fdw (work with postgres) and I found a lot of tutorial where foreign table are used. So, I'm actually searching a lot of solutions to moove my originals tables to foreign table.

Comment: postgres works with foreign tables way slower than with "local"

Comment: cstore_fdw mplements a columnar store for PostgreSQL and I think create foreign table is the only way to use it

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw:

> To load or append data into a cstore table, you have two options:
>
> - You can use the COPY command to load or append data from a file, a program, or STDIN.
> - You can use the INSERT INTO cstore_table SELECT ... syntax to load or append data from another table.

so follow the [example](https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw#example):
create foreign table and insert data to it from your local table.

Comment: I already tried but I have a problem. I copy all my data into a csv file (`copy basic_data to '/tmp/data_fdw2.csv' delimiter ';' null '';`
`COPY 8792481`
But when I'm doing the query to insert my table into my cstore table (`copy basic_data_cs from '/tmp/data_fdw2.csv' delimiter ';' csv;`), I have only `COPY 374327`

Comment: maybe because data is transformed?.. is not it the purpose of cstore?

Comment: Its in my file. When i go into the file and i search the number of rows, its 374327 and not 8792481

Comment: I'd ask it as new question - it has nothing to do with foreign data wrapper and is either or bug or some human mistake