# Bug during COPY in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, cstore-fdw

I have a table named `basic_data` which contains more than 8 millions rows and I want to copy all this data into a CSV file.

So I use the `COPY` command like this :

`copy basic_data to '/tmp/data_fdw.csv' delimiter ';' null '';
COPY 8792481`

This work great but when I want to insert my data into another table with exactly the same schema (but it's a foreign table), I had this following error:

`ERROR:  value out of range: overflow`

Comment: evaluated from http://stackoverflow.com/q/44064004/5315974

Comment: I think it is extension limitation - contact citus data I'd say

Comment: try playing with options from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cstore-users/iHxR1t86iPg

Comment: You should figure out which row causes the problem an edit the question with details about how to reproduce.

Comment: I think its because I have too many rows, when I try to copy something like 100 000 rows, it works well

Comment: @AlexandreS. Too many rows should not be a problem. My guess is that you have a column type with limited scale/precision, e.g.: `NUMERIC(8,2)`.